# How to remove <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1"> from SOAP Request

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wcf-binding, soap-client

I am consuming a third party Duplex service(assuming this as there is a callback contract implemented). Below is config section. The service throws exception saying it can't understand tag in request XML "a:To mustUnderstand="1".

```
 <endpoint address="http://vmsvalservice-uat.rpdata.com:80/vms-valuation/soap/soapws"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="VMSSSO_CustomBinding" behaviorConfiguration="VMSSSOHeader" 
    contract="VMSSSOService.VmsPort" name="VmsPortSoap11">
  </endpoint>

<binding name="CustomBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" allowInsecureTransport="true"/>
<compositeDuplex clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8080"/>
<oneWay maxAcceptedChannels ="2"></oneWay>
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
<httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"/>
</binding>
```

Request XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:76901ce5-0bab-42e2-ac76-18eddf367d25</a:MessageID>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://vmsvalservice-uat.rpdata.com/vms-valuation/soap/soapws</a:To>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
```

I tried two ways to fix it.

1. I have tried BeforeSendRequest to control the behavior but this tag is added in Soap envelope after this event is called.
2. Tried to reset the mustUnderstand to 0 by writing a class and overwriting the MustUnderstand property as then XML is accepted.

Is there anyway I can stop this tag going out or reset MustUnderstand.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I verified the xml and found that a  is required by the schema.  You should validate the entire XML as follow : From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Paste your XML into the window making sure there is only one identification line.  Any errors will show in the Error list just like compiler errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:76901ce5-0bab-42e2-ac76-18eddf367d25</a:MessageID>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://vmsvalservice-uat.rpdata.com/vms-valuation/soap/soapws</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved this by explicitly removing the given header and reinserting it afterwards:

```
    newHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("To", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", m.Headers.To.ToString(), false);
    index = m.Headers.FindHeader("To", Definitions.WSA_NAMESPACE_FULL);
    m.Headers.RemoveAt(index);
    m.Headers.Insert(index, newHeader);
```